# Spring constructor injection

Tags: spring, constructor-injection

Is it possible to construct an object manually and let some other arguments be injected by Spring?

e.g.

```
 class A 
 @Autowired
 private SomeDao dao;
 A(String x, String y) {}
```

Comment: Can you  give some background? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is using field injection, not constructor injection.

The best way is generally to use JavaConfig. Your `@Bean` methods can take parameters (which Spring will autowire), which you can combine with your other options when you call `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport class it's what you are looking for, try to invoke:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use autowireBean from the [AutowireCapableBeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBean-java.lang.Object-). Given your applicationContext, you call [getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html#getAutowireCapableBeanFactory--) and then autowire your instance:

```
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean( new A("x", "y" ) );
```